# Keras, custom "how different is" loss function definition issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm currently building a CNN-LSTM encoder-decoder anomaly detector by reconstruction on Keras, following the directions of of [Malhotra et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00148.pdf) but with the CNN encoder difference, still I'm aiming to use the loss(objective) function defined there as:

[image]
Where X is a sample of a time series of L steps, and x(i) is the i-th real vector and x'(i) the reconstructed. The total training set is that s_N.

I made the loss function, but I think it's not behaving well, so I appeal to you and your knowledge to see if is this my error source or I might need to find elsewhere:

```
def mirror_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    diff = tf.square(tf.norm(tf.substract(y_true, y_pred), axis = 1))
    return K.sum(diff, axis = -1)
```

It bothers me that I have to use both tensorflow and keras.backend because I wasn't able to find the "norm" on keras.backend.

Comment: are you sure that the axis in the `diff` declaration is correct in terms of how you structured your data. Though this is nominally different from MSE, I would not expect it to behave too differently from optimizing with MSE (different derivative by a const factor), could you try out MSE? How does it work?

Comment: Another possibility is that sometimes square loss can have very large gradients, especially if you data is not normalized. You can try taking a square root and use standard RMSE error. If that does not help, I would suggest asking this question on stats.stackexchange.com with detailed explanation of what exactly "not behaving well" means and various standard graphs: training/validation loss/accuracy, gradient norm, etc.

Comment: @modesitt I think it is defined well, only because the definition of the loss function would launch a dimension-related error otherwise, since it must compare 2 tensors of same shape. (The model aims to reconstruct the input tensor). The main difference when using MSE and this function is the magnitude of the loss, MSE starts with something like 0.8, while this one launches over the thousands.  As I see, both are having a bad convergence which menas I may need to find another error source

Comment: @iga I actually had problems wtih normalization before, but I added a sklearn MinMaxScaler( ) to the data acquisition. But convergence is still slow.